# hot to get network adapters names except microsoft's ones

Tags: powershell, networking, adapter

Hi I want to get the name of all the network adapters from my computer except the Microsoft ones.

```
ServiceName      : RTL8168
MACAddress       : ---------------
AdapterType      : Ethernet 802.3
DeviceID         : 0
Name             : D-Link DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
NetworkAddresses : 
Speed            : 1000000000

ServiceName      : kdnic
MACAddress       : 
AdapterType      : 
DeviceID         : 1
Name             : Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
NetworkAddresses : 
Speed            : 

ServiceName      : e1express
MACAddress       : ---------------
AdapterType      : Ethernet 802.3
DeviceID         : 2
Name             : Intel(R) 82562V-2 10/100 Network Connection
NetworkAddresses : 
Speed            : 9223372036854775807

ServiceName      : tunnel
MACAddress       : 
AdapterType      : Tunnel
DeviceID         : 3
Name             : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
NetworkAddresses : 
Speed            : 100000

ServiceName      : 
MACAddress       : 
AdapterType      : 
DeviceID         : 4
Name             : Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
NetworkAddresses : 
Speed            :
```

This is what I have so far (I don't know the correct regular expression that shows only the adapters that doesn't contain "Microsoft" on its Name object)

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^[^M]"}
```

I want to get this output:

```
ServiceName      : RTL8168
MACAddress       : ---------
AdapterType      : Ethernet 802.3
DeviceID         : 0
Name             : D-Link DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
NetworkAddresses : 
Speed            : 1000000000

ServiceName      : e1express
MACAddress       : -------------
AdapterType      : Ethernet 802.3
DeviceID         : 2
Name             : Intel(R) 82562V-2 10/100 Network Connection
NetworkAddresses : 
Speed            : 9223372036854775807
```

Thank you guys in advance, I know this one is easy :)

Comment: `get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "microsoft"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powershell something like

```
Get-NetAdapter | where-object Name -NotContains Microsoft
```

**upd.:** in comments already answered